# Angular reloads the entire page when changing url location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router and html5 url mode. 
Given the code below, whenever I load the application say at `http://localhost:3000` I'm redirected to `http://localhost:3000/home` (as expected).

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui-router']);

app.config($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');

    // use HTML5 urls
    $locationProvider
          .html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
          })

    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/home');

    // For any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

}
```

The **first problem** is that changing `html5mode` to `false` doesn't seem to have any effect. The html5mode will be active anyway and the only way to use the classic mode is to comment the whole code block:

```
$locationProvider
    .html5Mode({
        enabled: false,
        requireBase: false
    })
```

**Q:** What is wrong here?

The **second problem** is when the classic mode is active (non html5mode), and I am for example on `http://localhost:3000/hello` then I'll redirected to `http://localhost:3000/hello#/home`.

**Q:** Why the `hello` part is not taken away?

The **third (main) problem** is when for example I'm already on the `home` state or another *ui-router* state and I manually change the browser url to point to another state (or the `home` state itself). In this case instead of going to that state the entire browser window is reloaded, re-booting the angular application.

**Q:** What I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)`?

Comment: yes. This disable/enable html5 mode. It doesn't accept an object as argument because I realized I use angular 1.2.24: https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.24/docs/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Comment: Still missing the solution for the 2nd and 3rd problem tough..